# in c#, how to call a function according to db value without if/else

Tags: c#, dynamic

I am trying to call a function according to db value without using if/else or case. My sample code is below and I think it will explain itself better.

```
LogoObj.Data ms = logoApp.NewObj(LogoObj.DataObjType.Item); // Item
```

the "Item" information comes from a SELECT query. The "Item" could be "Customer" as well. Therefore, I dont want to write code like below.

```
if(datatable_result.Rows[0][0].ToString()=="ITEM")
   ms = logoApp.NewObj(LogoObj.DataObjType.Item);
else if(datatable_result.Rows[0][0].ToString()=="CUSTOMER")
   ms = logoApp.NewObj(LogoObj.DataObjType.Customer);
.........
.........
.........
```

Can I have a piece of like below, because this something I need

```
LogoObj.Data ms = logoApp.NewObj(LogoObj.DataObjType.XXXXXDB_VALUEXXXXX);
```

Comment: What are the possible values which you can get from database?

Comment: Dictionary<string,Action> ?

Comment: @FiN, as I told before, I dont want to use case because there are more than 200 values

Comment: @RahulTripathi, there are 200 possibilities.

Comment: Is `LogoObj.DataObjType` an `Enum`?  You can probably just look up the right one using `Enum.Parse`

Comment: @JamesThorpe, yes it is ENUM

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`Enum.Parse`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kxydatf9(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
var enumValue = Enum.Parse(typeof(LogoObj.DataObjType), datatable_result.Rows[0][0].ToString(), true); //true = ignore case
ms = logoApp.NewObj(enumValue);
```

If you have the potential for items in the database to not match any of the enum values, you should instead use [`Enum.TryParse`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.enum.tryparse(v=vs.110).aspx) and check to ensure it has correctly parsed the value before calling `NewObj`.

Answer (score 1):

So this is what i'm thinking:
Get the type of object you want to create from the data table.
Use reflection to loop through LogoObj. DataObj Type Enum.
If your type of object is found call New_Obj() method with it.

```
 string str = datatable_result.Rows[0][0].ToString();
 LogoObj.Data ms;
 foreach (var dataObjType in Enum.GetValues(typeof(LogoObj.DataObjType)))
 {
            if (str == dataObjType.ToString())
            {
                ms = logoApp.NewObj(dataObjType);
            }

 }
```

Comment: Ah too late, the Parse method is even better.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for a programmatic way of calling a method within an assembly based on the method name?
Considered using Reflection? Note : below code is pseudocode.

```
MethodInfo mi = obj.GetType().GetMethod("MethodName");
var result = mi.Invoke();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use reflection, but if you're going to perform many calls, I'm going to suggest you this project made by Marc Gravell: [Fast-Member](https://code.google.com/archive/p/fast-member/):

> .NET reflection is slow... well, kinda slow. If you need access to the
>   members of an arbitrary type, with the type and member-names known
>   only at runtime - then it is frankly hard (especially for DLR types).
>   This library makes such access easy and fast.

For example:

```
// This should be done in some initialization code and reuse the accessor
// everywhere in your app...
var accessor = TypeAccessor.Create(LogoObj.DataObjType.GetType()); 

string propName = datatable_result.Rows[0][0].ToString().ToLowerInvariant();
propName = propName[0].ToUpper() + propName.Substring(1);

ms = logoApp.NewObj(accessor[LogoObj.DataObjType, propName]);
```

Answer (score -1):

What about

```
var table = new Dictionary<string,Action> {
                                           {"ITEM", () => Console.WriteLine("Item!")},
                                           {"CUSTOMER", () => Console.WriteLine("Customer!")},
                                          };
```

And use it like

```
table[datatable_result.Rows[0][0].ToString()]();
```

If you need a result from the call, use `Func<>` instead of `Action`:

```
var ms = table[datatable_result.Rows[0][0].ToString()]();
```